# Cannot add ui widget to Eclipse RCP view on mousedown event

Tags: eclipse, view, widget, addition, rcp

I'm trying to add new widgets on an RPC view by clicking on an existing button. The code that I'm using is the following:

```
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {

    parent.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Button btnNewButton = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
    btnNewButton.setText("New Button");

    btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
                    Button b=new Button(parent,SWT.BUTTON1);
                    b.setText("asdasd");
        }
    });

}
```

The buttons are getting added on the view but are not visible. If I resize the view then they become visible. Why is this happening and how can it be solved? 
I need somehow to refresh the view or call the event that the resize action calls.

The attached code works without problems in standard java applications.

Thank you,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Call the layout method of your parent `Composite` when you add a widget:

```
btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
                Button b=new Button(parent,SWT.BUTTON1);
                b.setText("asdasd");
                parent.layout();
    }
});
```